# BIRT report download as PDF doesn't contain the data

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, reporting, birt

I have a report generated with BIRT report
I use birt viewer with pdf format

```html
 <div>
   <birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="${rpt}" baseURL="${baseURL}"
    pattern="frameset"
    height="500"
    width="970"
    format="pdf">
    <birt:param name="startDate" value="${reportFromDate}"></birt:param>
    <birt:param name="endDate" value="${reportToDate}"></birt:param>
    <birt:param name="customerId" value="${customerId}"></birt:param>
   <%--  <birt:param name="branchName" value="${customerId}"></birt:param> --%>
   </birt:viewer>
  </div>
```

This way report work fine and generated the PDF out put

But when I click the download button of generated PDF view and download the Report as pdf doesn't contain any of the records in generated view.

BIRT forum not been that helpful for this matter. If someone have an idea please help me out here. Thanks!!

[Refer following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2P2h.png)

Comment: you should use (sql)logging to find out if the exact same query is used. This is not always what you expect. The download button most likely generates the report again, but maybe without these parameters or some (faulty) defaults in the report xml

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen  Yes you are right. It generates the report again. What happened me here is when generating report again parameters are not passing. So it gives the blank pdf. As a solution I changed BIRT viewer to "html"  insted of "pdf" . HTML view has export option which includes all including pdf. There it all work correctly :)